# Facebook Graph API - See who the user have invited to an event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been going through the Facebook Graph API documentation for some time now, and I can't seem to find  a way to find who a user have invited to an event. Is there any way to achieve this?

So far I've only been able to get a complete list of the people invited :/

Comment: I have an answer to your [deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811880/nearest-even-hour). If you reopen it I can post it for you.

Comment: I've added my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't that information from the Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/event/invited

It seems that you can´t get all the users who have been invited by a specific person, but according to the docs you can get a list of all the invited users.

Comment: Yeah, this is only solution I've found. Do you think there is any way to invite people through my site, so I can track it instead?

Comment: no, it´s in the link i posted: "You cannot invite people to events via the Graph API."

Comment: but that list has no information on who invited each person :( Is there any alternative to that? This information is available on facebook, why not on Graph API?

Comment: no, there is no alternative, it´s just not possible. just because it´s available on facebook does not mean it´s available on the graph api.