# Nearest next even hour

Tags: php, time

I'm looking for a way to get the nearest even hour and the associating day. Getting the hour haven't really been a problem but getting the day have been.

Technically I just need to find the next nearest even hour on the clock with the day associated to the hour, so if the next even hour is 0 then it should ahead one day, as It's the start of a new day.

Example:

> It's 2014-11-08 22:05:00 -> the next nearest should then be 2014-11-**09** 00:00:00
>
> It's 2014-11-08 20:35:37 -> the next nearest should then be 2014-11-08 22:00:00 (this part is easy)

What would be the easiest way to do this?
This is currently what I've tried, but they've all struggled around midnight sadly

**Try #1**

```
$date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i'));
$nextDate = (intval($date->format('H'))+2) % 24;
if ($date->format('H')+2 > 24 || $nextDate == 0)
{
    if($date->format('H')+2 > 24)
        $nextDate = $date->format('H')+2 - ($date->format('H')+2 - 24);
    dd($nextDate);
    $nextDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 days")) .' '. $nextDate . ':01';
}
else
    $nextDate = date('Y-m-d') .' '. $nextDate . ':01';
```

**Try #2**

```
$hours = [0=>2, 1=>2, 2=>4, 3=>4,4=>6,5=>6,6=>8,7=>8, 8=>10, 9=>10, 10=>12, 11=>12,12=>14, 13=>14,14=>16,15=>16,16=>18,17=>18, 18=>20,19=>20,20=>22, 21=>22, 22=>0,23=>0];
if ($hours[date('G')] == 0)
{
    if(date('G') != 0)
        $nextDate = date('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $hours[date('G')] . ':01:00';
    else
        $nextDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 days")) . ' ' . $hours[date('G')] . ':01:00';
}
else
    $nextDate = date('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $hours[date('G')] . ':01:00';
```

Comment: how is the nearest even hour to 20:35:37 -> 22:00:00? Shouldn't the nearest be 20:00:00?

Comment: In that sense yes. Not what I'm looking for though, edited :).

Comment: Ah i see... Well that certainly makes it more difficult to answer a question, when your questions doesn't portray what you are looking for.

Comment: Post some code detailing what you've tried and what's going wrong with it.

Comment: I've added the code I've tried as requested :) they are both failing around midnight ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish your goal, you could add the missing time to your DateTime object:

```php
$dt = new DateTime('2014-11-08 22:05:00');
$sec = $dt->format('G') * 3600 + $dt->format('i') * 60 + $dt->format('s');
$sec %= 7200;
$dt->modify("-$sec second")->modify('+2 hour');
echo $dt->format('c');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/218956)</kbd>

<sub>Be careful about DST.</sub>